# batch file to check if exe is running if so taskkill

Tags: loops, time, batch-file, flash, taskkill

I'm having problems with the firefox Flashplayerplugin eating up too much ram and lagging my system when it's not in use. The only solution I found was killing the flashplayerplugin while using firefox, uninstalling, reinstalling or a fresh firefox install or new profile doesn't solve it; however, it's becoming very tedious having to check taskmanager all the time and kill it and the flashplayerplugin always seems to start on it's own.

The question I have is if it's possible to create a batch file to check if FlashPlugin_11_8_800_94.exe is running and kill it after a period of time (5-10 seconds) and continue running the batch file actively, in a loop, scanning if FlashPlugin_11_8_800_94.exe has started again, then kill it after 5 - 10 seconds, rinse and repeat?

Edit:

Found a batch file and modified it, but also seems to be missing some perimeters to actively search if it's running, even when it is not. It doesn't work either way though.

```
@echo off

:search
TASKLIST|FIND "FlashPlayerPlugin"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% = 0 THEN (GOTO found)
TIMEOUT /T 5
GOTO search

:found
taskkill /im FlashPlayerPlugin_11_8_800_94.exe
```

--

This batch file doesn't work either.

```
set tasklist=%windir%\System32\tasklist.exe
set taskkill=%windir%\System32\taskkill.exe

-------------------------------------------------------
:STOPPROC
    set wasStopped=0
    set procFound=0
    set notFound_result=ERROR:
    set procName=%1
    for /f "usebackq" %%A in (`%taskkill% /IM %procName%`) do (
      if NOT %%A==%notFound_result% (set procFound=1)
    )
    if %procFound%==0 (
      echo The process was not running.
      goto :EOF
    )
    set wasStopped=1
    set ignore_result=INFO:
:CHECKDEAD
    "%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" 3 /NOBREAK
    for /f "usebackq" %%A in (`%tasklist% /nh /fi "imagename eq %procName%"`) do (
      if not %%A==%ignore_result% (goto :CHECKDEAD)
    )
    goto :EOF
-------------------------------------------------------

:MAIN 

call :STOPPROC FlashPlayerPlugin_11_8_800_94.exe
```

Comment: If the above code works fine to end the process once, just add `:loop` to the top and `goto loop` to the bottom. Another question, why do you need to check if the process is active. Why not make the batch file just keep on closing any instance of `FlashPlayerPlugin_11_8_800_94.exe`? That would be much easier.

Comment: Neither of the batch files I posted work, they both display a blank prompt when executed.

Answer (score 3):

```
taskkill /im FlashPlugin_11_8_800_94* /f >nul 2>&1
```

Comment: The `/f` comes before the `/im`

Comment: in fact it doesn't matter..If you don't believe me you can test it that way :-)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who still might find it useful:
This is a small script that scans **tasklist** for processes containing **processname** once every 5 seconds. For example, if you put "notepad" for the **processname**, it will end processes like "notepad.exe" and "notepad++.exe". To use the script, copy and paste the following into notepad and save has "simple_pk.cmd". **processname** can have any characters except double quotes("), ampersands (&), or commas (,).

```
::Simple monitor and kill process
@echo off&prompt :&mode con cols=50 lines=10

set processname=flashplayerplugin

:loop
cls&echo Searching for %processname%...
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /fo csv ^|FINDSTR /I /C:"%processname%"') do call :killprocess %%a
ping -n 6 127.0.0.1>NUL
goto :loop


:killprocess
echo. |set /p d=killing %*...
taskkill /f /im "%*">nul 2>&1
set err=%errorlevel%
set success=Success
if not %err%==0 set success=fail (err code: %err%)
if %err%==128 set success=fail (process not found)
echo %success%&goto :eof
```

This is a slightly different version of the same script. This will only end processes that match the whole name exactly:

```
::Simple monitor and kill process (exact name)
@echo off&prompt :&mode con cols=50 lines=10

set processname=FlashPlayerPlugin_11_8_800_94.exe

:loop
cls&echo Searching for %processname%...
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /fo csv ^|FINDSTR /C:"%processname%"') do call :killprocess %%a
ping -n 6 127.0.0.1>NUL
goto :loop


:killprocess
set name=%*
set name=.,;%name:"=%;,.
echo %name%|FINDSTR /C:".,;%processname%;,.">nul || goto :eof
echo. |set /p d=killing %*...
taskkill /f /im "%*">nul 2>&1
set err=%errorlevel%
set success=Success
if not %err%==0 set success=fail (err code: %err%)
if %err%==128 set success=fail (process not found)
echo %success%&goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

Your IF is not correct:

```
@echo off

:search
TASKLIST|FIND "setup.exe"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (GOTO found)
TIMEOUT /T 5
GOTO search

:found
taskkill /im setup.exe
```

Comment: can you tell us what teh numbers with the K mean on teh right hand side. Also why is this command showing if `@echo off` is present?

Answer (score 0):

More simpler form

```
@echo off
:search
TASKLIST|FIND "setup.exe"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (taskkill /im setup.exe
exit)
TIMEOUT /T 5
GOTO search
```

Answer (score -1):

I was looking over the first bit of code at top and I find a way, I believe. This is what I got; really simple.

```
@echo off
cls
:start
timeout /t 5
tasklist|find "explorer.exe"
goto found
goto start
:found
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
goto start
```

Of course, any program will work.